# Page footer not displaying properly: overlapping with body (before navigating)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my report I have a body and a page footer. The problem is that the page footer is getting overlapped with the body.

This problem only occurs when the report is displayed for the first time. When I navigate through the report, the footer becomes fine. In other words: the problem is with the first time the report is rendered.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about the report, help us reproduce it. In addition it would help if you tell us what you've debugged / tried to do to fix it.

Comment: What i did i put a textbox of some height, you can say of height 14 inch, then the footter displays fine but has additional space between the report body and report footer. Also the space issue is after the report footer as well

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem. This issue rose when I was trying to put a  **table within a rectangle to make its size constant** whereas the table content is about to  increase its width while rendering. So try removing the rectangle or increase it's size and page width.

Answer (score -1):

R you using table for each jsp file?

The best way to resolve this problem :-
try to insert jsp(s) in a table. then u'll never get this kind of problem
you can try below example code..

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td><jsp:include page="jsp/header.jsp"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><jsp:include page="jsp/report.jsp"/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><jsp:include page="jsp/footer.jsp"/>
      </tr>
</table>
```

so your page will look perfectly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has something to do with jsp files. We are using Microsoft Reporting Tool for this which doesn't involve any html